# Finding residential buildings with overpass-turbo?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, residential

I am looking to find all residential buildings with overpass-turbo.eu.
I am trying to use the following query:

```
way
  ["building"~"residential|house|terrace|detached|apartments"]
  ({{bbox}});
(._;>;);
out;
```

However, not many residential buildings are found in this way.

Which tags should be used to find the buildings through overpass-turbo, which may be multi-use but also residential (residential and commercial, or residential and retail...)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not all buildings have a corresponding typology tag. Many are just tagged with [building](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building)=yes (currently [81%](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building#values) of all buildings). Some might have an additional [building:use](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building:use)=residential tag.

Remember that the OSM database is primarily populated by volunteers. Some are too "lazy" to enter the building topologies, others just don't know or care about it. Feel free to improve the situation by contributing to OSM.

Comment: You might be able to derive dual use buildings from those tagged building=yes by also querying lots of POIs (amenity=*, shop=*, office=*) and then using some GIS afterwards to perform point in polygon analysis.

Comment: Thank you for the replies!

@scai: Is this ```building:use=residential``` the only residential tag left, among upper 5 mentioned, as far as you know? I tried searching for it, and it's very rare.
Although I understand what you said about volunteers being lazy.

@til_b: How would those POIs identify if a building is also residential or not?

Comment: @marco You can take a look at the [taginfo page for building:use](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys/building%3Ause#values) to see the most common values. taginfo generates statistics about OSM tags and their usage. This page also shows that you are correct and this key is rarely used (600k usages compared to 200M buildings in OSM).

Comment: Thank you once again for the useful reply @scai !!
I understand that it may be difficult to manage open database as OSM, where each user can tag what ever he wants.
Nevertheless, I am very surprised, that the OSM community itself, hasn't came up with at least a suggestion, on the best way of tagging these sorts of multi-use buildings (residential + commercial/retail...).

Comment: Theoretically you can add multiple [values separated with a semicolon](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Semi-colon_value_separator), for example `building:use=residential;commercial`. However various software won't handle this correctly.

Comment: You have been of great help once again Alexander. I owe you for all this help!