# Get all residential addresses within bounding box

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

How can I get all the residential addresses within a bounding box?  I tried the query from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239492/finding-residential-buildings-with-overpass-turbo) (reproduced here):

```
way
  ["building"~"residential|house|terrace|detached|apartments"]
  ({{bbox}});
(._;>;);
out;
```

The bounding box is whatever that is visible in the map area.

Whatever map I try this out on in [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu), nothing is returned.

Comment: please tell us more about your process (what is your BoundingBOX, which query exactly ? ) what's wrong with the answer of https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/239504/53945

Comment: That answer addressed my problem.  I was expecting addresses to show up in the results because there were clearly residential buildings in the displayed map.  If I zoomed out, I saw addresses returned in the results.  However, many the results did not have street addresses.

Comment: How about searching for all nodes, ways (and relations) with addr:housenumber=* and then intersect them with landuse=residential. From this selection remove every node, way (or relation), which is tagged as a non-residential adress.

Answer (score 4):

"residential addresses" is not quite the same as "residential buildings" (which the other question was about).  Where I'd start is:

1. Go to https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org , type"addr:street" in the search box and press enter.
2. Click the "Overpass turbo" link.
3. Zoom in
4. Run Query

Be aware, though, that depending on where you're searching not everything may have street addresses added, and street addresses might be separate from buildings and from points of interest.

Comment: addr:residential should be a more appropriate tag

Comment: @HugoRoussaffa No - have a look at https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/search?q=addr to see the numbers of each of the addr keys in use.