# OSM: Downloading all street names + adress number + coordinates of a city?

Tags: openstreetmap, export, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

For a statistical analysis my company wants me to create an Excel sheet containing every building's adress in a city, like this:

**City name | area code | street name | house number | longitudinal Coord. | lateral Coord.**

The coordinates aren't all that important though.
Duplicates are fine too.

Is there a way to export this, mabye just by using overpass-turbo.eu?
I was able to get the individual street names on there, but not house numbers.

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256440/get-all-residential-addresses-within-bounding-box